# Total number of intersections of multiple linestrings - not working as expected

Tags: postgis

I have a table of gps tracks as follows (points_geom is SRID 4326) -

```
tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created) AS track from 
    dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
)
```

*imei is the device_id*

I am trying to calculate "how much" the various individual device tracks are intersecting with each other (with a buffer distance of 5m). So I add the following code:

```
intersections as 

(SELECT ST_NumGeometries(ST_Collect(st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track)))
FROM tracks AS l1
JOIN tracks AS l2 ON ST_DWithin(l1.track::geography, l2.track::geography , 5)
where l1.imei != l2.imei 
GROUP BY st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track))
```

**Code update:** I have **added** the following to get the final counts -

```
select sum (agg_count)
from intersections
```

I do get a result set, but I don't think my approach is correct, since no matter if I put the buffer distance in ST_DWithin as 5 or 5000, the answer is the same! which is unlikely.

Should I use a cross join lateral instead of the simple join?

Is there a better way I can calculate "how much" the tracks overlap, perhaps calculating the distance of overlap instead of counting multi points of intersection?

Comment: I am wondering what your tracks look like.  Have you looked at the output of `st_makeline`?  You have no ordering so I assume the lines generated look like spiderwebs, which would affect your analysis.  Second, you don't need to calculate the intersection geometry (`st_intersection`).  All you need to do is count how many tracks from L2 with a different imei than L1 are `st_dwithin`  5m of each line in L1.  You don't need `st_intersects` or `st_intersection`

Comment: I am ordering by time when making the tracks, please help!

Comment: oh, yep.  Sorry, I missed that.  Your tracks should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dwithin search, you're trying to do too many things.  You just need to find how many other tracks are within 5m of each track.  This could work:

```
select imei, count(intersectedimei) from
(
  select l1.imei, l2.imei intersectedimei
  from
  tracks l1, tracks l2
  where l1.imei != l2.imei and 
    st_dwithin(l1.track::geography,l2.track::geography,5)
) foo group by imei;
```

Comment: is intersectedimei an alias for l2.imei?

Comment: yes alias for l2.imei

Comment: do I really need to group by imei? it seems that if I just want total number, then I can remove this grouping by imei

Comment: but I need to calculate the extent of how much they overlap, I don't think this does that right? so I don't just want to see if track A and track B intersect. I want to see how much they intersect.

Comment: I want to see the total number of  points of intersections. so if track A intersects track B 5 times, and track C 10 times, then total intersections will be 15.

Comment: You can group by imei and intersectedimei if you want intersections per imei.

Comment: The 'how much' question is more complex to answer.  You need to buffer the tracks, then get the intersection of the buffer and intersecting tracks, then get the length per imei. I'll think about it.

Comment: If I post a new question, can you please attempt to answer it

Comment: regarding the 'how much' question you just mentioned

Comment: my intersection code in the question should answer the 'how much' question right? theoretically at least

Comment: I have posted the 'how much' scenario as a new question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/441646/211549