# Total length of intersecting lines - comparing multiple lines to each other

Tags: postgis, intersection

I have a tracks table as such:

```
tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created) AS track from 
    dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
)
```

*imei is the device id* /
*points geom has SRID 4326*

I am trying to figure out 'how much' the tracks of one device intersect with the other. I want to know the length of the total intersection as a measure of 'how much' intersection occurred across different devices.

Here is a diagram which illustrates intersection of tracks, I want to find the total length of the intersecting tracks (where tracks of one or more devices intersect):
[image]

Here is my current code to achieve this (buffer distance of 5m or less will be considered intersection):

```
intersections as 

(SELECT ST_NumGeometries(ST_Collect(st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track))) as agg_count 
FROM tracks AS l1
JOIN tracks AS l2 ON ST_DWithin(l1.track::geography, l2.track::geography , 5)
where l1.imei != l2.imei 
GROUP BY st_intersection(l1.track, l2.track))
```

This does not seem to work because even if I change the buffer value from 5
to 5000, the results are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to buffer the tracks, get the intersection, get the total intersection length per intersecting imei.  Then you can compare the lengths.  More length = more intersection.

```
with tracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    st_setsrid(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created),4326) AS track from 
    dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
),
bufferedtracks AS
(SELECT 
    imei,
    st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_MakeLine(points_geom ORDER BY time_created),4326)::geography,5)::geometry geom from 
    dataset  
    GROUP BY imei
)
select imei, intimei, st_length(st_union(intgeom)::geography) intlength
from
(
select a.imei, b.imei intimei, 
    (st_dump(st_intersection(a.geom,b.track))).geom intgeom 
  from
  bufferedtracks a,
  tracks b
  where a.imei != b.imei and st_intersects(a.geom,b.track)
) allints
group by imei, intimei;
```

Comment: thanks so much for the elegant solution

Comment: May you have a happy and blessed life!

Comment: Thank you!  Interesting question.  I'm glad I could help you.  I wish you all the best!

Comment: Hi ,the total intersecting lengths are quite high to be plausible, could there be any projection error in the code? thanks

Comment: Possibly setting the srid on the tracks will help.  I forgot about that.  See edits

Answer (score 2):

[ST_Within()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) returns a boolean. It won't help you much in your task, I guess.

What you should do is comparing how much *shared area* exist between buffers  for each pairs of lines.

Functions to play with are: [ST_Area()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) on the results of [ST_Intersection()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) between buffers as given by [ST_Buffer()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html).